# ASP.NET MVC Passing DataTime to View a

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a asp.net MVC4 web project it shows a list of production data for that day. I have added a datetime picker which allows the user to select a date that they want to show information for.

The problem i am having is i am not sure how to go about passing the information back to the view from the method i have inside the controller.

I have the date passing back to the controller. Inside the controller i am doing a LINQ statement that allows me to select only the production data for that day.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetProductionDateInfo(string dp)
    {
        DateTime SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dp);
        DateTime SelectedDateDayShiftStart = SelectedDate.AddHours(7);
        DateTime SelectedDateDayShiftEnd = SelectedDate.AddHours(19);

        var ProductionData =

            from n in db.tbl_dppITHr
            where n.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart
            where n.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftEnd
            select n;


        return View();
```

I am looking to get the Var ProductionData passed back to the view so that display it inside a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `ProductionData` directly to your View.

```
 return View(productionData)
```

And then in your View you could have `@model IEnumerable<Type>`

However, a better practice would be to create a strongly typed `ViewModel` to hold the ProductionData and then return the following:

```
 var model = new ProductionDataViewModel();
 model.Load();

 return View(model);
```

Where `model` a definition as follows:

```
public class ProductionDataViewModel { 

   public List<ProductionDataType> ProductionData { get; set; }
   public void Load() {
       ProductionData = from n in db.tbl_dppITHr
        where n.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart
        where n.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftEnd
        select n;
   }
}
```

Then in your view use the new strongly typed ViewModel:

```
 @model ProductionDataViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are returning nothing to your view here `return View();` this view just render view and no data will be passed to it.

if `ProductionData` is getting values then

return `return View(ProductionData);`

You can then use the values passed in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use a model, something like:

```
public class ProductionDataModel
{
    //put your properties in here

    public List<ProductionData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then create/return it in your `ActionResult`:

```
var ProductionData =
    from n in db.tbl_dppITHr
    where n.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart
    where n.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftEnd
    select new ProductionData
    {
        //set properties here
    };

var model = new ProductionDataModel
{
    Data = ProductionData
};


return View(model);
```

Then in your view, set your model at the top:

```
@model ProductionDataModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProductionData` variable should now be of type `IEnumerbable<tbl_dppITHrRow>`.

You can pass in the model from your controller using this code at the bottom of your action:

```
return View(ProductionData);
```

In your view, you can make this your model type by placing the following Razor code in your view's .cshtml file:

```
@model IEnumerbable<tbl_dppITHrRow>
```

Then, you can use your model in your view code:

```
@foreach(var row in Model) {
    <div>@row.Value</div>
}
```